# Viewing A-Frame output in mobile

Tags: android, google-cardboard, aframe

I have been fooling around with A-frame and created a bunch of entities and things like that. I am able to see the html output fine in my laptop. How can I port it to my Android mobile so that I use my VR gear to see the html result on my mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can just load the page on your mobile browser and go into VR mode.

Another solution is to integrate your html/js/css code into an application using crosswalk (https://crosswalk-project.org/) for example

Answer (score 0):

You can throw the following code to index.php:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

See the result with http://trithucmoi.edu.vn